# Selective Join in View Sql

Tags: sql, join

Here is pseudocode of what I am trying to achieve

```
Select * from TableA

if(TableA.criteria != 1)
    inner join TableB.criteria = TableA.criteria
```

I must do it in view can use sp, functions, etc.

Thanks for any help you will be able to provide

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help clarify the question.

Comment: data is so mess even I am having hard time to understand

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
Select a.*, b.* from TableA a join TableB b
   on b.criteria = case when a.Criteria = 1 
       then 1 else null end
```

Comment: I have tried to adapt your answer but my condition is actually not equal I have edited it. thank you but its not working this way

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a left join
     b
     on b.criteria = a.criteria and b.criteria = 1;
```

The `left join` will keep all rows in `a`, even when the `on` condition is not true.  The extra columns from `b` will be `NULL`, unless the criterias are both "1".

Comment: I have tried to adapt your answer but my condition is actually not equal I have edited it. thank you but its not working this way